# How to separate text in lines in a table in Lua

Tags: lua

```
local table_1 = {["choice"] = 'New Character(free)'};
```

this is the table, (free) need to be written in a different line

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you want the string to contain the newlines, or do you want to write a single-line string on multiple lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just format your source code you can simply write

```
local table_1 = {["choice"] = 'New Character
  (free)'};
```

If you need a linebreak in your string you can insert a newline character `"\n"`

```
local table_1 = {["choice"] = 'New Character\n(free)'};
```

Comment: by saying trhe first example do you mean it's only visual in code and not actually separated when the code is ran? The second one seems like what I need

Comment: @Arkston yes your quesiton was not very clear. the first example is just formatting of code. it has no effect on the string itself.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. Just tested, it's exactly what I needed.